# How to Add up the values in a Nested Collection using Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following `TicketDTO` Object:

```
public class TicketDTO {
    private LocalDate date;
    private Set<OffenceDTO> offences;
}
```

And every `OffenceDTO` has an `int` field - *penalty points*.

```
public class OffenceDTO {
    private int penaltyPoints;
}
```

I would like to add up the **penalty points** to a single `int` value by streaming the *Set of Offenses* of each *Ticket*. But only if the ticket's date is between the last two years.

I have collected tickets from the last two years, but now I have a problem in how to go through the offenses and count their points.

This is what I've written so far:

```
tickets().stream()
    .filter(ticketEntity -> isDateBetween(LocalDate.now(), ticketEntity.getDate()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: *"collect that penalty points to one int"* — What do you exactly mean? Would you like to sum all penalty points of all tickets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to collect the **penalty points** in a single `int` value by streaming the **set of tickets**

It can be done in the following steps:

- Turn the stream of filtered *tickets* into a stream of `OffenceDTO` using `flatMap()`;
- Extract *penalty points* from `OffenceDTO` with `mapToInt()`, that will transform a stream of objects into a `IntStream`;
- Apply `sum()` to get the total.

```
int totalPenalty = tickets().stream()
    .filter(ticketEntity -> isDateBetween(LocalDate.now(), ticketEntity.getDate()))
    .flatMap(ticketDTO -> ticketDTO.getOffences().stream())
    .mapToInt(OffenceDTO::getPenaltyPoints)
    .sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `tickets()` is a method that returns a `List` of `TicketDTO`, you could stream the `List` and filter its elements with your custom method `isDateBetween` (as you were doing).

Then **flat the mapping of each ticket to their corresponding offences**. This will provide you a stream of `OffenceDTO` whose `TicketDTO` is between the last two years (according to your `isDateBetween` method).

Ultimately, you can collect the points of each `OffenceDTO` by summing them with the `summingInt` method of the `Collectors` class.

```
int res = tickets().stream()
        .filter(ticketEntity -> isDateBetween(LocalDate.now(), ticketEntity.getDate()))
        .flatMap(ticketDTO -> ticketDTO.getOffences().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.summingInt(OffenceDTO::getPenaltyPoints));
```